# How to read a text file into a variable?

Tags: mysql, file-io

In MySQL, using the `LOAD DATA` command, I know that I can ***load*** a text file into some table, but what I want is to load the file content into a `text` variable.

For example, how can I customize this loading code so that it will set a variable (`productsXml`) rather than a table:

```
DECLARE productsXml text;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'products.txt'
INTO TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` -- I would like to set the productsXml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your text file has only `flat text` (I mean no delimited data). Then create your table `table_name` with only one column of `TEXT` type and load the data with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

```
create table table_name (`txtcol` TEXT null);
```

Then you can simply say get that column data to your variable like

```
DECLARE productsXml text;

select txtcol into productsXml from table_name;
```

**EDIT:**

You can as well use `LOAD_FILE` like below. Found [HERE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/how-do-you-load-a-data-file-into-a-specific-field)

```
SET @mytxtvar = LOAD_FILE('D:\\test.txt');
SELECT @mytxtvar;
```

Comment: Can I convert this table into a temporary one?

Comment: @YairNevet, Yes you can. it could be either `TEMPORARY` or `NORMAL` table. doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @YairNevet, You have two options as in answer ... choose either one which works for you.